# Git merge from a third branch

Tags: git

I have two branches, `homolog` and `development`.

`development` is ahead of `homolog`, but I want to make `development` a mirror of `homolog`.

If I could commit straight into development, I would say:

```
On branch development
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/development'.
$ git pull origin homolog
$ git add *
$ git commit -m "merges homolog into development"
```

But in my particular case, I am not allowed to commit straight into `development`, so I cannot perform the instructions above.

Instead, I have to create **a branch from** `development`, pull the code from homolog, and then push it (*via* pull request) to development.

What I've tried:

```
On branch development
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/development'.
$ git checkout -b my-cool-branch
Switched to a new branch 'my-cool-branch'
$ git pull origin homolog
```

My intention was to get the code from homolog at this point. But unfortunately, git says:

```
Already up to date!
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
```

What does not make sense at all (because I'm a noob).

Comment: Why don't you just get the commits from.`development` and push them to `homolog`?

Comment: What do you mean by "to make development a mirror of homolog"? Do you want to cut commits from `development`, so it it's not ahead of `homolog` anymore? Or do you want to add extra commits to `homolog`?

Comment: I want to make development identical to homolog.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Do you have changes in homolog that aren't in development? But you want to put them into development? Or have there been further changes in development, while you've created homolog from a previous commit, and you want to update homolog with the changes in development?

Comment: If homolog is ahead of development, then there is a common base. If you want development to match homolog, create a PR to merge homolog into development. Then homolog and development will be at the same point (besides a merge commit if you complete the PR with a merge vs. a rebase and fast forward completion).

Comment: A pull request can NEVER make development “identical to homolog.” You cannot fast forward merge using a pull request.

Comment: To be clear, I think you're answering the question from @Eugene with "I want to remove commits from `development` so it is no longer ahead of `homolog`. Is that right? If yes, this is similar to deleting `development` and replacing it with a copy of `homolog`. (The extra commits on `development` will be gone.) Additionally, you don't have permission to force push. If that's truly what you want to do, either you need to request permission to force push, or ask someone who has that permission to do the force push for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to make development identical to homolog

First of all, this is wrong:

```
On branch development
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/development'.
$ git pull origin homolog
$ git add *
$ git commit -m "merges homolog into development"
```

The `commit` at the end does *not* merge homolog into development. What merges homolog into development is the `pull` at the start! A `pull`, by default, is a `merge`. The other stuff just appends any uncommitted material — but you probably would not have been allowed to do the `pull` if there were any uncommitted material, so it's pretty much pointless.

Okay, with that out of the way: what you are hoping `git pull origin homolog` will do is merge homolog into development *as a fast forward*. That is indeed what will happen if homolog diverged from development and is purely ahead of development (i.e. not also behind development at all).

But then we come to your statement here:

> I have to create a branch from development, pull the code from homolog, and then push it (via pull request) to development.

Okay, well, if that rule is truly the case, then what you want to do is *impossible*. The reason is that a pull request is nothing but a protracted merge at the server side. But no form of pull request will permit you to do a fast-forward merge at the server side. The closest you can get is a "rebase and merge":

https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-request-merges#rebase-and-merge-your-pull-request-commits

That cherry picks the commits from homolog onto development. But they are not the *same* commits; they are copies. So development and homolog will not be "identical". Still, they should result in the very same appearance: that is, after such a pull request merge, checking out development and checking out homolog would give the same outcome in the working tree, which seems to be the bulk of what you are after.